# Flutter array looping list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making my own flutter application, but I ran into a problem. I am creating a Breakfast class

```
class Breakfast {
  String foodTitle;
  String foodCalories;

  Breakfast({this.foodTitle, this.foodCalories});
}
```

From this class i create an array with objects of that class

```
class BreakfastFood {
  List<Breakfast> _breakfastFoodData = [
    Breakfast(
     foodTitle: "Bread",
     foodCalories: "100",
    ),
    Breakfast(
     foodTitle: "Soup",
     foodCalories: "50",
    ),
  ];

  int _foodTitle = 0;
  int _foodCalories = 0;

  String getFoodTitle() {
   return _breakfastFoodData[_foodTitle].foodTitle;
  }

  String getFoodCalories() {
    return _breakfastFoodData[_foodCalories].foodCalories;
  }
```

}

I have created a component which gets the foodtitle and foodCalories and puts them in a widget.

Now i want to make a function that loops through the objects of the _breakfastfoodData and shows them. But I don't know how to loop through the list and show all the objects seperate from eachother.

Comment: I think you can use the listview.builder and take advantage of it's index property to loop thorought all the ojc in the array.

Comment: Your information is insufficient. Are you aware that `_breakfastfoodData` property is hidden/private? You need a method that let to access to it and can loop it (`for`).

Answer (score 0):

_breakfastFoodData in your code is private property (because it begins _), you should change to breakfastFoodData.

- You use ListView.builder to build your list:

  ```
   List<Breakfast> datas= new BreakfastFood().breakfastFoodData;
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: datas.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${datas[index].foodTitle}'),
        );
      },
    );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define your class as here:

```dart
class BreakfastFood {
  List<Breakfast> _items = [
    Breakfast(
     foodTitle: "Bread",
     foodCalories: "100",
    ),
    Breakfast(
     foodTitle: "Soup",
     foodCalories: "50",
    ),
  ];

  List<Breakfast> get items => [..._items];
}
```

and Then call it threw list view for display all items:

```dart
BreakfastFood foodData = BreakfastFood();

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: foodData.items.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('${foodData.items[index].foodTitle}'),
      subTitle: Text('${foodData.items[index].foodCalories}'),
    );
  }
)
```